# I cannot understand why this CSS style is wrong

Tags: html, css

I try to print some text in red but it doesn't work. I can't see why.

`<div style="error-style">This is an error message</div>`

Css file:

`.error-style {
  color: #ff0000;
}`

Comment: Change `style=` to `class=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... You did a typo...

`<div class="error-style">...`

What you need is probably a good expresso.

Comment: You're right, or better go for a nap...

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<div class="error-style">This is an error message</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`style="..."` must be actual CSS code. What you want is `class="error-style"`.

Answer (score 1):

You put style instead of class. Don't worry, it happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="error-style">This is an error message</div>
```

CSS:

```
#error-style { color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: -1 How should it help for the style tag to use an ID?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was just going to fix that. Now it's good.

Comment: better but still no good solution, because when you talk about error messages than you must have in mind that this error messages can exist more than one time on the page. So, instead of an id you use a class.

Comment: That's actually a great point, listen to Sven and make it a class.

Comment: We must use id for unique elements. A page can have some errors so the class attribute is better !

Answer (score 0):

use #f00 insted of #ff0000

view this link for mor information http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color